# Create multi panel application in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, panel

I'm developing WPF MVVM application and I want to create a Window with many panels that changes when user choose another panel from navigation.

[image: Desired application]

I've read [this](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/) article but it's not working due to `Can't put a Page in a Style` error. I can't find any answer about how to create a WPF application that navigate through different panels in one single window, how I can achieve what I want using MVVM pattern?

Comment: "it's not working due to Can't put a Page in a Style error" -- sounds like you took the example code, scrambled it randomly, and gave up. It's not a good idea to make large arbitrary changes in code you don't yet understand. All that does is break everything. Instead, make very small changes, one by one, and undo them if they break the code.

Comment: I believe the error occurs becouse I'm using newer wpf/.net version and they disabled that option for some good reason. I fully understand the code, the problem lays when I want to "translate" viewmodel class display into actual Panel. I've post that tutorial just for example and proof that I actually did something before asking, I think that this solution for my problem was good back in '10, but I need something that fits my needs in newer WPF and is working with MVVM pattern.

Comment: Oh, you fully understand the code. That's fine then. What did the answer turn out to be?

Comment: Why not use a `TabControl` and change the style till you like it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an `ContentPresenter` and bind it to the `MainWindow` ViewModel and set the DataTemplate for each ViewModels.

```
<ContentPresenter  Name="WindowContent" Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"/>

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MainViewModel}">
        <views:MainView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

And so when the binded property is changed, ContentPresenter display proper ViewModel and due to DataTemplate, the actual View.

```
public IPageViewModel CurrentPageViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return _currentPageViewModel;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_currentPageViewModel != value)
        {
            _currentPageViewModel = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentPageViewModel"));
        }
    }
}
private IPageViewModel _currentPageViewModel;
```

Every ViewModel implements simple `IPageViewModel` interface so only ViewModels could be set as content of `ContentPresenter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can place various panels in a Grid, sharing the same space (overlapping) and change Visibility to make "Visible" only the one you want shown.
I've used this thecnique same time ago, and is compatible with MVVM too.